# Get an svg file as text dynamically in Vue

Tags: vue.js, svg, webpack, leaflet

Im using a library (leaflet) that requires html as string. I have svgs saved in assets. So far, here is my method

```
getSvg( file ) {
  try {
    const name = file.substr( 0, file.lastIndexOf( '.' ) )
    return require( `@/assets/icons/profile/${ name }.svg` )
  } catch ( e ) { 
    return null
  }
}
```

How am I able to get the svg element as a string from this? I have also tried doing this

```
'<img :src=${ svg }/>'
```

But that doesnt draw the svg

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [`raw-loader`](https://webpack.js.org/loaders/raw-loader/) to get the raw text of the SVG file:

1. Install `raw-loader`

   ```
   npm install -D raw-loader
   ```
2. Prefix the import path with `!!raw-loader!`, and get the `default` property of the imported value:

   ```js
   return require( `!!raw-loader!@/assets/icons/profile/${ name }.svg` ).default
   ```